# 20.04: Why can't you turn on top-bar menus in Terminal in Preferences?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

In Ubuntu 18.04 the topbar of the Terminal window contains the following pull-down menus:

File - Edit - View - Search - Terminal - Help

In 20.04 they were missing. I DID manage to turn them on, by right-clicking inside the Terminal window. But I think it would have been more logical if you could just turn them on in Preferences.

The worst thing is that I have to turn on the menu bar every time I enter the terminal... That seems kind of primitive to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know WHY it's impossible to turn them on from Preferences (I hate that too!), however it is possible to turn them on permanently via dconf-editor (you need to install it first). From top level, go to org/gnome/terminal/legacy and set "headerbar" to false.
(BTW. After you set "headerbar" to false, the option to turn on/off menu bar does appear in Preferences)

Comment: Thank you! But what do you mean by setting it to 'false'? When I go to org/gnome/terminal/legacy, the 'headerbar' doesn't have an on/off button. Instead there is the word 'nothing'. But if I click on 'headerbar' I can 'turn on' a 'custom value' and I can set that 'custom value' to 'False'. Is THAT what you mean? :-)

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Yes - it worked! Thank you!